# Reload the current page in angula6 with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, angular6

when we reload the current page(angular6), i got the below error.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /chapters/chapters

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate a more? 
Because if the route is correct and component is correctly defined in routing, then it shouldn't be throwing an error.

Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. 
Its clearly saying that route is not found. Please check the routing file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. my application is working fine. when we refresh the current page , i got the above error.